# Retrieve Facebook-email in one click

Tags: php, facebook

I have a webpage, and I want to retrieve the e-mail people use for Facebook. How can I create a button on my page, which asks the users for permission to just give me their e-mail, and then loads their e-mail into my PHP-script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put up this link:

```
<a href="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?type=user_agent&client_id=APP_ID
&redirect_uri=http://yourwebsite.com/fbaccess.php
&scope=email">
Add Facebook
</a>
```

You need to replace `APP_ID` above, with your application id.

Check out the full tutorial here:

http://www.9lessons.info/2011/01/facebook-graph-api-connect-with-php-and.html